# Navigation bar. Text inline with and on top a horizontal rule?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have been trying to get a navigation bar with text inline with a horizontal rule & text on top of the horizontal rule.

[image]

I'm pretty new to to css and bootstrap and was wondering if it is possible to have it centered and span 8-10 columns

Something kind of like this

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-1" style=""></div>
<div class="col-md-1" style="">TEXT</div>
<div class="col-md-8" style="">horizontal rule with text on top</div>
<div class="col-md-2" style=""></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting close.

I would use the offset classes instead of empty columns. Other than that you just need to place your navigation in your `.col-md-8` DIV.

My example below has some CSS for the navigation so it will display inline. By default `<li>` elements are set to `display: block;` and will take up the whole width of their parent element. Basically, they'll end up stacking.

The only major thing of note is the text in the first column and attempting to vertically align it with the border/horizontal rule. There's a couple ways to this. In my example I've chosen to double the default `line-height` that Bootstrap uses.

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="callout col-md-1 offset-md-1">
      TEXT
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">

      <nav class="primary-nav">

        <ul>
          <li>One</li>
          <li>Two</li>
          <li>Three</li>
          <li>Four</li>
        </ul>

      </nav>    

    </div><!-- .col-md-8 -->

  </div><!-- .row -->

</div><!-- .container -->
```

```css
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.callout {
  line-height: 2.85714286; /* twice Bootstrap's line-height */
  text-align: center;
}
.primary-nav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
.primary-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

The [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hwtmfz7e/).

Comment: Thank you.
I do have a question about the code you provided.  When I have tried using it and looking at it on the JSFiddle site the part where the "Text" is, is above the horizontal rule, is there anyway to get it in front and inline with the horizontal rule?

Comment: Can you provide an example? It sounds like you're asking if the horizontal rule should appear as if the rule is striking through the text. What I've provided is very close to what you have in your post. You might have to re-size the example to see that. If the window is too small, the first `Text` will appear above the text sitting above the horizontal rule. Changing the classes from `*-md-*` to `*-xs-*` will prevent the stacking from occurring at larger viewport widths. This is the Bootstrap grid system at work.